# The second fundamental form of the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am trying to understand how one computes the second fundamental form of the sphere. Looking at the example on page 10. 
http://www.math.miami.edu/~galloway/dgnotes/chpt5.pdf

Here I understood everything up to the point
$\frac{\sigma(t)}{|\sigma(t)|}=\frac{\sigma(t)}{r}$.
Could anyone explain to me why is 
 $|\sigma(t)|=r?$

Many thanks

Comment: The curve is on the sphere!

Comment: $\sigma(t)$ is a curve on the sphere, therefore $||\sigma(t)||=r$ for all $t$.

Comment: why is the length of the curve the same as the radius at all t...im lost

Comment: Are you sure $|\sigma(t)|$ is the length of the curve? I'd expect $\sigma(t)$ to just be a point on the curve, hence $|\sigma(t)|$ to be the distance of this particular point to the origin. Which indeed equals $r$ for a point on the sphere.

Comment: @HSN my understanding is that $\sigma(t)=x(u^1(t),u^2(t))$ is a vector function in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and you meant this vector-valued function can be regarded as a point on the sphere. (the curve lies on the sphere) ? I cannot see this myself pictorially. please help.

Comment: @HSN  Do you mean, a curve on the sphere at a particular time $t$ can be viewed as a point on that sphere?

Comment: That's roughly what I mean, yes.